# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int

Tags: c#, gridview, edit, type-conversion

i want to update data in my gridview. However it shows me this error when i try to update it. here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID" 
OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductName">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
             ErrorMessage="Invalid" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtboxProductName"
            ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z ]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductDescription">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxProductDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductDescription") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid" 
            ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtboxProductDescription"
            ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z ]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:ImageField HeaderText ="ProductImage" DataImageUrlField="ProductImage" SortExpression="ProductImage" ControlStyle-Width ="10">

        <ControlStyle Width="50px"></ControlStyle>

        </asp:ImageField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductQuantity">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductQuantity") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxProductQuant" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductQuantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid" ControlToValidate="txtboxProductQuant"
            ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression=^[0-9]*$></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductPrice">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductPrice") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxProductPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductPrice") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid" ControlToValidate="txtboxProductPrice"
            ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression=^[0-9]*$></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
    <%--<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />--%>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdel" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" 
        OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirm Delete?');"></asp:LinkButton>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and here is my update code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //Finding the controls from Gridview for the row which is going to update  
        //Label id = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_ID") as Label;
        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        TextBox ProductName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtboxProductName") as TextBox;
        TextBox ProductDescription = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtboxProductDescription") as TextBox;
        TextBox ProductQuantity = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtboxProductQuant") as TextBox;
        TextBox ProductPrice = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtboxProductPrice") as TextBox;
        conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=Authorship;Integrated Security =True");
        conn.Open();
        //updating the record  
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Products set ProductName='" + ProductName.Text + "',ProductDescription='" + ProductDescription.Text + "',ProductQuantity='" + ProductQuantity.Text + "', ProductPrice='" + ProductPrice + "' where ProductID='" + userid + "'", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        //Setting the EditIndex property to -1 to cancel the Edit mode in Gridview  
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        //Call ShowData method for displaying updated data  
        gvbind(); 
}
```

the error is specifically in the textbox productprice because when i try to make the FindControl(""), its working but returns 0 as a value. but the other data are working fine. and when i insert the findcontrol(txtboxProductPrice), it shows me the error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int.
```

my table contains

```
ProductID - int
ProdcuctName - varchar(500)
ProductDescription - varchar(500)
ProductImage - varchar(500)
ProductQuantity - int
ProductPrice - int
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you have part of the code like this:

```
+ "', ProductPrice='" + ProductPrice + "' where ProductID='" +
```

ProductPrice is a textbox, so you need to use property `Text` to access the text:

```
+ "', ProductPrice='" + ProductPrice.Text + "' where ProductID='" +
```

Also, very important note: NEVER create your query by concatenating command like you did, because you are vulnerable to [SQL Injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). There are thousands of articles online about how to fix this issue, make sure to read them and implement your query in a proper way.

Comment: any idea on how will i remove the textbox(edit mode) on one of the fields in gridview? i tried not declaring it inside the <edittemplate> but still, when i click on update, a textbox becomes visible

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Products set ProductName='" + ProductName.Text + "',ProductDescription='" + ProductDescription.Text + "',ProductQuantity='" + ProductQuantity.Text + "', ProductPrice.Text='" + ProductPrice + "' where ProductID='" + userid + "'", conn);
```

Use ProductPrice.Text instead of ProductPrice